# Html5 scroll effect on images

Tags: html, scroll, mask, effect

I need to reproduce the effect created on this site about Team :

```
http://www.case-3d.com/#about
```

I try to look on the web but I can not find a tutorial or site that talks about this html5 effect .... I was wondering if someone could help me ?

thanking you in advance

Comment: Why someone would vote you down for this question just blows my mind. Man there's some idiots on this site - this is a legitimate question, one which is helping me understand how that site works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the element you can find out they use [a canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/). Looking further you can see the script that uses the canvas (by searching in the inspector for the ID or some similar techinque) is called "1". I pulled some of the basic structure so you can follow it:

```
//This part sets up the canvas and gets the pictures
function setupCanvas() {
  // Get canvas and context references
  teamCanvas = document.getElementById("stage1");
  teamContext = teamCanvas.getContext("2d");
  // Get images references
  img1 = document.getElementById("01");
  img2 = document.getElementById("02");
  ...

   // This part sets the initial position of the shapes
   // You can see that it is based of the window size and in reference to each other
   // Shape #1
   x1_1 = teamCanvas.width / 2;
   x1_2 = teamCanvas.width;
   x1_3 = teamCanvas.width;
   x1_4 = 0;
   x1_5 = 0;
   y1_1 = ssp1_1 = 929 + diff;
   y1_2 = ssp1_2 = 2000 + diff;
   y1_3 = ssp1_3 = 4000;
   y1_4 = ssp1_4 = 4000;
   y1_5 = ssp1_5 = 2000 + diff;
   // Shape #2
   x2_1 = 0;
   x2_2 = teamCanvas.width / 2;
   x2_3 = teamCanvas.width;
   x2_4 = teamCanvas.width;
   x2_5 = 0;
   y2_1 = ssp2_1 = 3000;
   y2_2 = ssp2_2 = 4000;
   y2_3 = ssp2_3 = 3000;
   y2_4 = ssp2_4 = 6000;
   y2_5 = ssp2_5 = 6000;
   ...
   // Some other stuff goes here, I didn't copy all of it       
 }

 // Then it goes into this function to handle the scroll and redraw it on the canvas
 function redrawAbout(scrollPosition) {
   // Refresh canvas
   teamContext.clearRect(0, 0, teamCanvas.width, teamCanvas.height);
   var scrollAmt = scrollPosition / maskModifier;
   // Redraw
   // Mask #1
   if (scrollPosition > -4000) {
     teamContext.save();
     teamContext.beginPath();
     teamContext.moveTo(x1_1, ssp1_1 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x1_2, ssp1_2 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x1_3, ssp1_3 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x1_4, ssp1_4 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x1_5, ssp1_5 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x1_1, ssp1_1 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.clip();
     teamContext.drawImage(img1, 0, -200);
     teamContext.restore();
   }
   // Mask #2
   if (scrollPosition <= -2100 && scrollPosition > -5900) {
     teamContext.save();
     teamContext.beginPath();
     teamContext.moveTo(x2_1, ssp2_1 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x2_2, ssp2_2 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x2_3, ssp2_3 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x2_4, ssp2_4 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x2_5, ssp2_5 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.lineTo(x2_1, ssp2_1 + scrollAmt);
     teamContext.clip();
     teamContext.drawImage(img2, 0, -200);
     teamContext.restore();
   }
```

In essence, they create some geometric shapes based on x and y co-ordinates, cut the images to fit within their respective geometric area based on those variables, calculate how much is being scrolled (through another plug in I believe), and redraw everything based on how far a user has scrolled.

Inspect element is an incredibly useful tool, learn to use it

When asking questions on StackOverflow, stay away from generics like this. Try to solve it yourself and post what you've tried so far and what is giving you trouble. Give detail and be articulate. If you do that you won't be down voted and you'll get relevant, all around good answers

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Zeaklous I try to use the javascript code case-3d.com but it generates me any data:image/png;base64... The canvas and images are nevertheless very present ... if you need here is the url where I test http://dev.av-prod.com/creanet3d-about/

Comment: Of course Zeaklous, this is only for me and understand how it works. I am a beginner and I just thought html5 recover their script to better understand how it works .... This is also why I'm asked if you had tutorials ... I'm not a thief, much less a thankless but having no other source to experiment it seemed more appropriate to make use of this one as a base ....

Comment: The way they (and most business sites) structured their site you cannot copy/paste the code and have it work. You must use the techniques they used and add your own content to it. Copy parts as you need them (like the parts I posted in the answer - they are the part you want)

Comment: ok I changed only way to not use that part of the script I need

Comment: Thanks @Zeaklous - the balanced approach to your answers are a refreshing change on StackOverflow.